# I am looking for references for a research work on predatory prices, do you know where I can read about it?

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request

A simple research work for my intermediate microeconomics course. I searched for it and didn't find it on Varian's and Pindyck's.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Google Scholar search results for "predatory pricing economics"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=predatory+pricing+economics&btnG=):

1. [The current state of the law and economics of predatory pricing](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2117658?casa_token=NhmpPsPBcFwAAAAA:WLh8qAF0HhS2AagK5TZ5Wx_MU0Us2AZCWZdAQnOEQxC572zpE0Rtc-93ICqhMj-xsaz_fCVWgK7xdzEL3duqgBactoJxpKpW4ZGmg_kfcSASykb0w5o) 
   AK Klevorick - The American Economic Review, 1993
2. [Predatory pricing: Strategic theory and legal policy](https://heinonline.org/hol-cgi-bin/get_pdf.cgi?handle=hein.journals/glj88&section=60) 
   P Bolton, JF Brodley, MH Riordan - Geo. LJ, 1999 - HeinOnline
3. [Stopping above-cost predatory pricing](https://heinonline.org/hol-cgi-bin/get_pdf.cgi?handle=hein.journals/ylr111&section=31) 
   AS Edlin - Yale LJ, 2001 - HeinOnline
4. [The economics of predation: What drives pricing when there is learning-by-doing?](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.104.3.868) 
   D Besanko, U Doraszelski, Y Kryukov - American Economic Review, 2014 - aeaweb.org